# CK Kernel For Quantal Quetzal?

Tags: kernel, patch

Are their any pre-compiled kernel packages for Ubuntu 12.10 that provide the CK patchset, or at least the BFS scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the packages provided by [liquorix.net](http://liquorix.net/).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: liquorix.net is for debian. Can it be used in ubuntu 12.04 .

Comment: I probably wouldn't use kernels made for other distros due to the problems it could create.  Though at this point the question is moot because I've switched back to Arch Linux.